# execute php script on background (without exec)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to load some data on each login, but this php script take some time to run and I don't want users to wait for a minute on blank screen.

I would like to trigger data loading process and redirect user to home as a normal login.

I cannot use exec because restrictions of hosting provider, so I am trying to use ajax for execute background.php and javascript for redirect. (windows.location)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"> </script>

</head>


<body>

    <script>
            $(function ()
              {
                 $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://myweb.com/background.php'
                   });
              });


            window.location="http://myweb.com";

    </script>

  </body>
```

if I comment windows.location line, then background.php script finish ok, but on any kind of redirection (header location in php, windows location in javascript), script does not execute.

I need to redirect to home (or any other part of my web site) without interrupting background.php execution.

¿Any idea?

Comment: Does your host allow use of [ignore_user_abort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) if so you should be able to use that so that the script continues even if the user stops the request

Comment: I've included ignore_user_abort(true); at the beginning of a script (for testing purposes) and it doesn't fail or warning,  thus I suppose hosting provider allows it, however, I tried to use it on background.php script and beheivor remains the same

Comment: Yes, you will definitely need ignore_user_abort for this. Also, your window.location assignment might happen before the browser begins the AJAX request. Please look at the event handlers for $.ajax, and update your window location AFTER the ajax request has connected the server (but BEFORE the server sends an answer).

Comment: Thanks, @PatrickEvans ignore_user_abort(true) at the beginning of background.php scripts works fine. I don't know why first time I tested it doesn't work.